# how to load image from file using MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

My browse button code is

```
void CFileOpenDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
 // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
 CFileDialog dlg(TRUE);
 int result=dlg.DoModal();
 if(result==IDOK)
 {
  path=dlg.GetPathName();
  UpdateData(FALSE);
 }
}
```

and this is the code for loading an image from resource but that does not work for loading an image from file. i know `LoadImage();` is used for this but how? how can i edit this code to load image from file. Plzz help.....

```
void CFileOpenDlg::OnBnClickedButton2()
{
 // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
CRect r;
CBitmap* m_bitmap;
CDC dc, *pDC;
BITMAP bmp;
m_bitmap = new CBitmap();
m_bitmap->LoadBitmapW(IDB_BITMAP1);
m_bitmap->GetBitmap(&bmp);
pDC = this->GetDC();
dc.CreateCompatibleDC(pDC);
dc.SelectObject(m_bitmap);
pDC->BitBlt(200, 200, bmp.bmWidth, bmp.bmHeight, &dc,0 , 0, SRCCOPY);
m_bitmap->DeleteObject();
m_bitmap->Detach();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

[MSDN LoadImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648045(VS.85).aspx)

```
HANDLE hBitMap = ::LoadImage(0, "c:\\mybmp.bmp",IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
CBitmap bmp;
bmp.Attach((HBITMAP)hBitMap);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to open .JPG, .PNG ... eventually you can use CImage (is a shared class between MFC and ATL)

```
CImage image;
image.Load ( "picture.jpg" );
image.Draw ( pDC , 200, 200 );
```