# How to read/write bmp file in MFC?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

How to read/write bmp file in MFC?
I did following way.

To read the BMP file

Used fread()/fseek()/ftell() function

For writing

Used fwrite() function and it is working.

Please suggest any other way doing of reading /writing bmp file in MFC.

Client will send bmp file and server will read and save the image file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to load image from file using MFC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029780/how-to-load-image-from-file-using-mfc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're developing for Windows use the ATL/MFC `CImage` class - it is part of the shared `MFC/ATL` classes.

Here is a good tutorial on [Bitmaps](http://tipsandtricks.runicsoft.com/Cpp/BitmapTutorial.html).